# Validating HTML5 Page

Tags: html, validation

I validated my website using:  https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload
and I got no errors.  However, the website recently changed and now I get these 2 messages:

Info: The Content-Type was application/octet-stream. Using the XML parser (not resolving external entities).
Fatal Error: Empty document, with no root element.

What do these messages mean?  How do I correct the error?

The settings I used were: Encoding: utf-8   document type: HTML5

SIMPLE HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>


<link href="css/omnicode.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
</script>
<![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </header>
  <hr>
  <p> TEXT </p>
  <hr>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you still getting errors after adding the closing `div` element? The HTML is reported as valid when I tested it with the closing `</div>` added.

Comment: When I click file upload: Encoding: utf-8 document type: HTML5.

The code I pasted in my question: shows this:

Info: The Content-Type was application/octet-stream. Using the XML parser (not resolving external entities).
Fatal Error: Empty document, with no root element.  

I have a closing </div> in my code, so I do not understand why I need to add one.

Comment: If I copy/paste your code in to the checker it validates without error. There must be something about the file you are uploading. Are you using Windows/Mac/Linux/Other operating system to create the file, and in which application?

Comment: I've also tried saving your sample HTML (with the div fix) to a file and uploading it to the checker. It validated it as HTML and found no errors.

Comment: I copied and pasted my code in the checker: and I got this message: 
Info: The Content-Type was text/html. Using the HTML parser.
Info: Using the schema for HTML with SVG 1.1, MathML 3.0, RDFa 1.1, and ITS 2.0 support. When you mentioned "with the div fix", are you referring to my closing </div> before </body>?

Comment: I have a Mac operating system.  Before W3 Validator made changes on their website, I load my file up and the errors and warnings were user friendly by listing errors and warnings.  After the W3 Validator made changes to their website, the Clean up Markup with HTML-Tidyfeature does not work.  The code I pasted in my question is exactly the file I uploaded.  Did you select HTML5 and utf-8?

Answer (score 1):

It could be because you have opening tags that are not closed. I put your code in to the checker and it complained about the body element being found before the div is closed:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">  <!-- no closing tag for this div -->
  <header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </header>
  <hr>
  <p> TEXT </p>
  <div>
  <hr>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div> 
</body>
```

```
Message filtering
Info: The Content-Type was text/html. Using the HTML parser.
Info: Using the schema for HTML with SVG 1.1, MathML 3.0, RDFa 1.1, and ITS 2.0 support.
Error: End tag for  body seen, but there were unclosed elements.
From line 27, column 1; to line 27, column 7
Error: Unclosed element div.
From line 17, column 1; to line 17, column 23
```

Fix that and rerun the tests.

Comment: <hr> is self closing, in HTML5 it don't need <hr />, hence the <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue when using the old w3 validator and Safari as the uploading Browser; If you upload using Chrome it should work fine, or if you cut and paste it should work fine. Also, if you upload using Safari to the "new school" validator it will work as well.

http://html5.validator.nu/

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine but some tags need to be closed like your hr's

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>


<link href="css/omnicode.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
</script>
<![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </header>
  <hr />
  <div>
  <p> TEXT </p>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since I am using HTML5, the hr tag does not need to be closed.  I put <div class="container" without the closing tag, and I still get errors and one of them is that I need a closing > tag after <div class="container" >